# Display panel over another panel for web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I was looking for an answer, but could not find anything helpfull yet.

I have a gridview with some data (from SQL database) and an option to delete a row. Before deleting the row I want the user to confirm the delete (pupup window). I know how to create a popup with javascript, but I don't like the apperance of that popup. I would like to make ky own "popup".

I was thinking of overlaying one panel (where I put text (Label) and some buttons (OK, Cancel)) over the panel where I have the gridview. Something like in the picture. How would I accomplish something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the Ajax control toolkit popup?

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Popup.ashx

This seems to do exactly what you are looking for for you.

Comment: this looks like it could work :) How do I style this popup? CSS?

Comment: Also have a look at this example http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: It lets you set a class for the background and you can style the content that you define with CSS like any other HTML

Comment: The other plus point about using this rather than doing it client side, is that you handle the result (yes/no) server side and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What about [JQueryUI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) with [custom](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) styling?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $dialog = $("#dialog");
        var $foo = $("input:submit[id$=foo]");
        var confirmed = false;

        $dialog.hide();

        $dialog.dialog({
            width: "300px",
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                OK: function (e) {
                    $dialog.dialog("close");
                    confirmed = true;
                    $foo.click();
                },
                Cancel: function (e) {
                    $dialog.dialog("close");
                    confirmed = false;
                }
            }
        });

        $foo.click(function (e) {
            if (!confirmed) {
                $dialog.dialog("open");
            }

            return confirmed;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Full [working example can be downloaded from here](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/JQuery/jQueryUI/ModalDialog.aspx)

Comment: I was also considering jQuery, but have no actual experience with it. Will need to look up how to implement it in the code. any tips?

Comment: Thank you, but in the end decided to go with Ajax.